# Работа с Json/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть код страничка например редактирование профиля и вот код (*jQuery*)  который получает *Json* формат с *Java*:

```
$.getJSON('powodyKorektyPG.do', function(data) {
    tmp = data;
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        //console.log(data[i].idPowKor);
        $('#select_jsoni').append('<option value="' + data[i].idPowKor+ '">' + data[i].nazwaPowKor + '</option>');
    }
});
```

Можно ли так сделать что когда в `input` делаю изминения и по нажатию (`Submit`) я получаю этот *Json* формат , в котором записываю изминения и после этого всего этот *Json* формат уже с измененными данными отправить на сервер? Если да то как? Спасибо большое

Comment: я запутался что вы хотите в итоге. Можете по пунктам разбить, что именно вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Вам надо положить полученные данные в объект (JSON.parse) спокойно с ним работать, как с обычным объектом JS, по каким хотите событиям и т.п. а когда соберетесь отправлять его обратно на сервер сериализовать объект обратно в json (JSON.stringify)

Comment: @Grundy Мне нужно сначало во всех инпутах ввести значение ,дальше по нажатию (Submit) мне нужно принять Json c даными от аккаунта и в етот же Json файл записать даные с инпутов ,после всего етого нужно обратно отправить ето все на сервер

Comment: @Mike Мне нужно сначало во всех инпутах ввести значение ,дальше по нажатию (Submit) мне нужно принять Json c даными от аккаунта и в етот же Json файл записать даные с инпутов ,после всего етого нужно обратно отправить ето все на сервер

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понял, вы получаете массив значений для списка `<select>`, добавляете значения в список.

Происходят какие-то изменения в `<input>` и `<select>`, далее делается `submit` формы и в результате вы должны получить данные со всех элементов формы?

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // отменяем стандартную отправку формы
    var dataJson = JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray()); // получаем все данные с формы и подготавливаем их в json формат

    $.ajax({
        url:'powodyKorektyPG.do',
        method: 'post',
        data: dataJson,
        success: function(info) {
            console.log(info);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: на самом деле _JSON.stringify_ может быть и не обязательно

Comment: @Grundy возможно